# C# KeyDownEvent how to assign a two key combination?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keydown

I need a two keys combination in my KeyDownEvent in C# but dont know how to create it as I need it for a certain function probably LShiftKey + F4 but how to write it?

Like: `private void KeyDownEvent(int keyId, string keyName)
 case Keys.F4:
          ..............
 case Keys.F5:
          ..............
 case Keys.F6:
          ..............
 case Keys.LShiftKey+F7:`(?)

The code is incomplete as I just need to know how to write the two key combination.

If you need further information, just give the word. :)

Greetings

Comment: Keydown isn't really the right place for a chorded key check.  However, one thing you could do is check the state of the left shift key in your other key handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ModifierKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9byw5s2d(v=vs.110).aspx) static property to figure out if Shift is down or not:

```
case F7:
    if(ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
        // now you do your Shift-F7 logic
    break;
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to do this is use the Keyboard class available after .net 3.0

```
private void KeyDownEvent(int keyId, string keyNum)
{
   case Keys.F7:
      if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift)
   {
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

Another way to do this is make a boolean value outside of the method (global) that you can turn true when a key is pressed.  You will also need to attach to the KeyUpEvent to turn this boolean back to false when it's let up.  Here's an example:

```
bool shiftKeyPressed = false

private void KeyDownEvent(int keyId, string keyName)
{
   case Keys.LShiftKey: shiftKeyPressed = true;
   case Keys.F7:
      if(shiftKeyPressed){//do stuff}
}

private void KeyUpEvent(int keyId, string keyName)
{
   case Keys.LShiftKey: shiftKeyPressed = false;
}
```

Comment: Note that the former resides in the Presentation Foundation (WPF), which may or may not be an acceptable import.